# How to implement dialog content destroy function after close vuetify dialog?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js

I'm new to vuetify and as far as I know, there is no way [for now] to destroy the body of dialog when the user closes it.

Does anybody have an idea about it?
For forms we can make field values equal to null or smth else but what about other components.

Answer (score 6):

You can simply add a v-if to the v-dialog. This will get it removed completely from the DOM (destroyed) when closed.

```
<v-btn @click="showDialog = true">Show Dialog</v-btn>
<v-dialog v-if="showDialog" v-model="showDialog">
    <v-card>
        Hello World
    </v-card>
</v-dialog>
```

Comment: Yes, and it works. If you would like, show me your design and I can help you get it to work.

Comment: this doesn't work for me and the modal list still in the DOM?

Comment: It breaks CSS transition on close.